# Microsoft Intune API Bad Request

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I was calling the Patch API endpoint for Microsoft Graph API's for Intune in order to update the details of devices present in the portal.

PATCH `/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}`

But in response it is returning Bad Request.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "{  \"_version\": 3,  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 2e274924-5fe1-453f-d869-671abf922cfd - Url: https://fef.amsub0502.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices%28%27e002cd5b-f97f-4212-b0b6-38ae3e77938e%27%29/microsoft.management.services.api.shutDown?api-version=5021-04-16\",  \"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",  \"RetryAfter\": null,  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-05-31T08:44:54",
            "request-id": "c869f3f9-def1-4d7f-93af-16b458bc0b17",
            "client-request-id": "2e274924-5fe1-453f-d869-671abf922cfd"
        }
    }
}
```

I was following every step mentioned in the documentation. We checked the required permissions and all required permissions were provided. We also tried the beta version of API but that also didn't work. So please help me out here if someone knows a fix for this.

Comment: Which property are trying to update?